# Dynamically Resizing a ggplot2 Graph in R Shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, resize, size, shiny

I have tried this:

```
output$plot <- renderPlot({
  getPlot()
}, width=input$plotX, height=input$plotY) # referring to two numericInput boxes
```

But I get this error:

> Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() :    Operation not
>   allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something
>   that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)

The help text suggests that I use functions, and that within those functions I can refer to reactive values, etc. But having done something like that, I still get the same error...

Is there a way to allow users to resize the plot based on values they enter into the app?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can wrap a reactive value into a function using `shiny:::exprToFunction`.

For example,

```
output$plot <- renderPlot({
  getPlot()
}, width=exprToFunction(input$plotX), 
   height=exprToFunction(input$plotY)))
```

should do the trick.

Comment: Totally worked! Though if I make it too tall, the graph sort of spills into the next UI element like this: [img](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/H4wFTG-bgot-B2_d_QSze7MfTmU87fchPJTXtHXf5DqC_JPArl9lh8XkfX1q2Grw1PaoOe6jVLg=w1896-h776)

Also, the any way to change the resolution? It starts to look bad when the plot is set to too large a size... Maybe that would be a job for the ggplot() call?

Comment: I was actually looking for solution to your exact question yesterday then I figured it out. I guess you can modify the CSS overflow attribute of its container to avoid spilling. ;)

Comment: Hi @vocaloidict, did you ever figure out how to customise the height of the container itself so as to not have the plot overflowing?

Comment: Hi @XinYin, I'm using http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp as a reference for the overflow attributes but all of them try to dictate how to control the spill whereas I want the container to expand to fit its contents.